# How to input and exception

Tags: c#

Ok here is a code I am working on. I am trying to get an exception so that way if they dont have something in the box to save it will pop up and not let them move on till the put something there. Now I know when I run my program and click the save button its tells me this

> ArgumentException was unhandled

what does that mean. I know it says empty path name is not legal. But the path is whatever the user wants. I have been messing around with this and im trying to figure out what to do but still kinda confused. So what is the best way to try to go about it. Do I have to make a class for it to work or can I just add into my code. I got the other part fixed with the try and catch but I can not get it to work on this one or maybe I have putting it in the wrong spot.

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = txtFilePath.Text;    

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))          
        {
            foreach (string lines in employeeList.Items)
                sw.WriteLine(lines);
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))<--This is 
where is says Arugment exception was unhandled.              
            {    
                foreach (var item in employeeList.Items)
                    sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not if (File.Exists(path)) instead of if (!File.Exists(path))
 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the code in a try catch statement and in the catch you can generate a message to the user (maybe a javascript alert box)

Pseudo code...

```
try
{
    current code
}
catch (exception e)
{
    error message to user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(txtFilePath.Text))
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter new path");
    txtFilePath.Focus();
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    string path = txtFilePath.Text;

      if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
           ..... Your rest code
```

Comment: Well when you go this route it is giving off an error up top of the IsNullorEmpty part.

Answer (score 0):

This means that:

> path is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains
>   one or more invalid characters as defined by InvalidPathChars.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(path == "")
{
    // Alert user or throw Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'path' not corretcly.

```
ArgumentException   
path is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters as defined by InvalidPathChars.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.invalidpathchars.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I figured I would answer anyway.

All that's wrong with the code above is that there is a } in the wrong place.

```
If (not file exists)
{

   else 
   {
   }
}
```

the else should be down a bit further.

```
if(not file exists)
{
}
else
{
}
```